# Async await thread exception

Tags: c#, api, xamarin.forms, async-await, task

I have big problem with `Task` method, and async await.
I have 4 methods type:

```
 private async Task Name(parameters)
 {
 }
```

And how to I can call all 4 methods to execute parallel, and to optimize time execution. Focus is constructor. I try many things. I put some here how I call in constructor:

1.

```
Parallel.Invoke(
    () => OnLoadPrometDanKorisnikDatum(KorisnikID, PomocnaDnDDatnaDat, DatumVrednost).Wait(),
    () => OnLoadPrometNedelja(KorisnikID, PomocnaDnDDatnaDatNedelja).Wait(),
    () => OnLoadPrometMesec(KorisnikID, PomocnaVrednostMeseciPicker).Wait(),
    () => OnLoadPrometGodina(KorisnikID, 0).Wait()
);
```

This is work but when you go on page 2nd or 3rd time exception throw that `List` is empty which take data from API (some of method).

2. When try await `Name` method; and that 4 times that don't work.
3. I try to method be void don't task that don't work too.

I don't know what to do. First method execution is about 6,7 sec. Second method is about 4 sec. Third 6 sec. Fourth 6sec.

Final need me to execute 4 method parallely and wait all that data from that 4 method. Because from that data I fill data chart later. Is empty list throw exception.

Comment: This is very difficult to read; help the people who are trying to help you by formatting code as code, more clearly saying what your question is, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying; I've voted to re-open.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Task.WhenAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_WhenAll_System_Threading_Tasks_Task___) to let the methods execute in parallel:

```
await Task.WhenAll(
    OnLoadPrometDanKorisnikDatum(KorisnikID, PomocnaDnDDatnaDat, DatumVrednost),
    OnLoadPrometNedelja(KorisnikID, PomocnaDnDDatnaDatNedelja),
    OnLoadPrometMesec(KorisnikID, PomocnaVrednostMeseciPicker),
    OnLoadPrometGodina(KorisnikID, 0)
);
```

`Task.WhenAll` returns a new `Task` that completes when all the provided `Tasks` have completed.